# Australian immigration long-stay 457 visa - do we need to pay tax on our engagement ring?

Tags: visa, immigration, australia, customs, imports

We'll be moving from the UK to Australia later this year, on a long-stay 457 visa which has been granted for 4 years.

My fiancée will be moving with me, and we'll be getting married at some point before the 4 years is up. (Likely back in the UK)

After reading the [Duty Free concessions page on border.gov.au](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Duty-Free-concessions) I'm confused as to whether her ring would fall under the 'general goods' category. If so, it'd likely be well over the $900 personal limit, even if we combined our allowances.

My question: Will we have to pay duty + taxes on it? If so, how much? I'm seeing conflicting information here online, and Google wasn't much help - all I could find was info on Australians travelling abroad to buy rings.

---

More details:

- Diamond ring with platinum band, bought this year < 12 months ago in the UK
- We paid around £3400 for it, and have the GIA certificates etc
- She'll be wearing it on her hand throughout the flight and immigration
- We won't be selling it, and will be taking it back to the UK (or wherever we move onto next) in 4 years
- We'll be flying back once a year or so to visit friends and family

Comment: I know next to nothing about Australian custom laws, but I think if she will be wearing it, she doesn't have to pay customs on it. She still might have to declare it.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it, but it's fairly obvious it's a personal item and is not to be sold.  457 isn't PR, so in theory you'll be leaving again with it.

Much like if you bring an expensive laptop or camera.

Answer (score 0):

This does not attract duty.

"Personal effects of temporary resident"

Do a search with the relevant keywords, and the domain .gov.au to see the government department's clear policies.

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/entering-australia/duty-free

https://www.abf.gov.au/importing-exporting-and-manufacturing/importing/how-to-import/temporary-imports